# PHP shell_exec inserts CR character in CURL command, leading to server error 500

Tags: php, curl, shell-exec

I use the following test program to retrieve a website's content:

```
<?php

function getData( $url, $output ) {
    // set the path for CURL
    if (file_exists( '/var/lib')) 
        $curl = 'curl';
    else
        $curl = 'curl.exe';
    $curl .= ' --trace trace.txt --header "User-Agent: Some-Agent/1.0" ';
    echo "\nreading $url...\n";
    $buffer = shell_exec( "$curl -i \"$url\"" );
    // if this is a 301 redirection URL, follow it one step
    if ((preg_match( '~^HTTP.+? 301 ~', $buffer )) and preg_match( '~Location: (.+)~', $buffer, $location )) {
        $cmd = "$curl -i \"$location[1]\"";
        echo "$cmd\n";
        $buffer = shell_exec( $cmd );
    }
    file_put_contents( $output, $buffer );
}

// test with a URL that will be redirected:
getData( "http://www.onvista.de/aktien/fundamental/EISEN-UND-HUETTENWERKE-AG-Aktie-DE0006055007", "DE0006055007-AG.html" );
```

On my windows machine, this code runs fine. On a linux machine it returns a 500 internal server error.
This is the start of the trace file trace.txt:

```
== Info: About to connect() to www.onvista.de port 80 (#0)<br>
== Info:   Trying 217.11.205.10... == Info: connected<br>
== Info: Connected to www.onvista.de (217.11.205.10) port 80 (#0)<br>
=> Send header, 130 bytes (0x82)<br>
0000: 47 45 54 20 2f 61 6b 74 69 65 6e 2f 66 75 6e 64 GET /aktien/fund<br>
0010: 61 6d 65 6e 74 61 6c 2f 31 53 54 2d 52 45 44 2d amental/1ST-RED-<br>
0020: 41 47 2d 41 6b 74 69 65 2d 44 45 30 30 30 36 30 AG-Aktie-DE00060<br>
0030: 35 35 30 30 37 0d 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 55007. HTTP/1.1.<br>
0040: 0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 77 77 77 2e 6f 6e 76 69 73 .Host: www.onvis<br>
0050: 74 61 2e 64 65 0d 0a 41 63 63 65 70 74 3a 20 2a ta.de..Accept: *<br>
0060: 2f 2a 0d 0a 55 73 65 72 2d 41 67 65 6e 74 3a 20 /*..User-Agent: <br>
0070: 53 6f 6d 65 2d 41 67 65 6e 74 2f 31 2e 30 0d 0a Some-Agent/1.0..<br>
0080: 0d 0a                                           ..<br>
<= Recv header, 36 bytes (0x24)<br>
0000: 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 20 35 30 30 20 49 6e 74 HTTP/1.1 500 Int<br>
0010: 65 72 6e 61 6c 20 53 65 72 76 65 72 20 45 72 72 ernal Server Err<br>
0020: 6f 72 0d 0a  <br>
```

The only difference between the windows trace and this one is a CR character after the filename (ending in `DE0006055007`. How did get there and how can I suppress it? (And no, I don't want to use the PHP cURL module which leads to other problems.)

Comment: Could you try calling [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) on `$url`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http headers you get end with `\r\n`, as should. It seems `curl` on linux converts them to `\n` if it detects the output is tty, but try to redirect to a file and you'll see the `\r`s in there.

`.` in `preg_match` matches also `\r` character, so it becomes part of `$location[1]`. Simple solution is to `trim` it.

This doesn't happen on windows only because you can execute `curl -i "http://google.com`. The quotation is ended by the shell automaticaly after newline.

And you should really use `escapeshellarg`.

Comment: Thank you, Marek. I never realized that . matches \r - I thought it matches only printable characters (above ord 31). I replaced . with [^\s] and now it works.